# Julia reporting an extra ) when it doesn't exist

Tags: julia, syntax-error, pluto.jl

I have this for loop in Julia:

```
begin
    countries_data_labels = ["Canada", "Italy", "China", "United States", "Spain"]
    y_axis = DataFrame()
    
    
    for country in countries_data_labels
        
        new_dataframe = get_country(df, country)
        
        new_dataframe = DataFrame(new_dataframe)
        
        df_rows, df_columns = size(new_dataframe)
        
        new_dataframe_long = stack(new_dataframe, begin:end-4)
        
        y_axis[!, Symbol("$country")] = new_dataframe_long[!, :value]
        
    end
end
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
syntax: extra token ")" after end of expression
```

I decided to comment all of the body of the for loop except the 1st one and ran the cell each time after uncommenting to see which line was throwing this error and it was the 4th line in the body:

```
new_dataframe_long = stack(new_dataframe, begin:end-4)
```

There is no reason for this error to exist. There are no extra bracket pieces in this line.

Comment: This is an awful error message, but the problem is that `begin` and `end` can only be used within indexing expressions (eg `X[begin:end-4]`). I think this syntax error is absolutely awful and should be fixed though.

Comment: Actually master seems to deal with this better. There I'm seeing `syntax: "begin" at REPL[1]:9 expected "end", got ")"`

Comment: @OscarSmith Check the edit. I added my full cell.

Comment: This is an arrow dataframe so I want to get all columns from the beginning to the end minus the last 4 columns..

Comment: What you want is `firstindex(new_dataframe):lastindex(new_dataframe)-4`

Comment: are `firstindex` and `lastindex` built-in functions?

Comment: yeah. when you `x[begin]` is just fancy syntax for `x[firstindex(x)]` (similar for `end`). You can use `Meta.@lower` to see how these types of expressions are expanded.

Comment: Now its telling me that `
UndefVarError: findFirst not defined`. How can I import findFirst to my Pluto?

Comment: @0092: `findfirst` all in lower letters...

Comment: `firstindex(new_dataframe)` is always `1`, so you can write this more simply as `1:nrow(new_dataframe)-4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you mean here:

```
stack(new_dataframe[begin:end-4, :])
```

See the MWE example below:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a=11:16,b=2.5:7.5)
6×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Float64
─────┼────────────────
   1 │    11      2.5
   2 │    12      3.5
   3 │    13      4.5
   4 │    14      5.5
   5 │    15      6.5
   6 │    16      7.5

julia> stack(df[begin:end-3, :])
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      variable  value
     │ Int64  String    Float64
─────┼──────────────────────────
   1 │    11  b             2.5
   2 │    12  b             3.5
   3 │    13  b             4.5
```